# Activeadmin unable to change title for "Form" new or edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Am using rails 4 in my application with active admin gem.
i wish to change my page default title when am rendering or redirecting to new or edit page , but the below code is not working.

my code is

```
form :title => { :new => "New action", :edit => "Edit action"} do |f|
   f.input reason, :label => "Reason", :input_html => {rows: 5} 
end
```

but when i use the below code its working

```
def new
      @page_title = "New Action"
    end
def edit
      @page_title = "Edit Action"
   end
```

but after validation rendering on new page its not updating the title ,because its only rendering not redirecting ,

```
def create
      @object = Model.new(params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @object.save
          flash[:notice] = 'Saved Successfully'
          format.html { redirect_to collection_url }
        else
          format.html { render "new"  }
        end
      end
    end
```

how to solve this problem, can any one please help me

Comment: what is the aim? don't really understand. Please, add some info on how is it now, and how it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the @page_title in create and update method works .

after validation failed also that page title works when adding it into the create and update methods.

```
def create
      @page_title = "new  title"
       @object = Model.new(params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @object.save
          flash[:notice] = 'Saved Successfully'
          format.html { redirect_to collection_url }
        else
          format.html { render "new"  }
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if its works, set

> @page_title = "action_type"

where validation is getting failed i.e in else part.
Rendering page will pick the new @page_title value

Comment: Thanks, it works. while setting the @page_title at create method also works fine for me.. thanks for the help.